# How to update cart total after AJAX success

Tags: ajax

I am making a customized shopping cart. The Ajax code is updating record correctly. However, I am unable to update/refresh the cart total to reflect the changes made by the user until reloads the page.

## AJAX

```
(function ($) {

    $(function () {

        let response_alert = $('#response');
        response_alert.hide();

        let update_button = $('.gs-update-order-btn');
        let delete_button = $('.gs-delete-order-btn');

        // updated process
        update_button.on('click', function () {

            let data_type = $(this).data('type');
            let data_id = $(this).data('id');
            let row_id = $(this).data('row');
            let data_user = $(this).data('for');

            $(this).addClass('updating');

            $.ajax({

                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: ajax_vars.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'gs_update_cart',
                    nonce: ajax_vars.nonce,
                    type: data_type,
                    id: data_id,
                    row: row_id,
                    qty: $('#qty-' + row_id).val(),
                    group_user: data_user
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log(response);

                    let response_alert = $('#response');

                    if (response.success === true) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('success', response.data));
                    }

                    if (response.success === false) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', response.data));
                    }
                    gs_alert_stats();

                }
                ,
                error: function (response) {

                    console.log(response);

                    let error_message = (response.data === undefined) ? 'Something went wrong!' : response.data;
                    response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', error_message));
                    gs_alert_stats();
                }
                ,
                complete: function () {
                    update_button.removeClass('updating');
                }

            });

            gs_alert_stats();
        });

        // delete process
        delete_button.on('click', function () {

            let data_type = $(this).data('type');
            let data_id = $(this).data('id');
            let row_id = $(this).data('row');

            // ajax code here ...

            $('#data-' + data_type + '-row-' + row_id).detach();

            response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', 'Item deleted!'));
            gs_alert_stats();
        });


    });

})(jQuery);
```

## WordPress AJAX function

```
function gs_update_p_cart_ajax()
{

    // Check if user is logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
        // throw error if user is not logged in
        wp_send_json_error(__('Please login to order', 'group-shop'));

        // cross confirm to die
        wp_die();
    }

    // check and validate nonce
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));

        // cross confirm to die
        wp_die();
    }

    // prepare for data validation
    $type       = sanitize_text_field($_POST[ 'type' ]);
    $row_id     = absint($_POST[ 'row' ]);
    $id         = absint($_POST[ 'id' ]);
    $qty        = absint($_POST[ 'qty' ]);
    $group_user = absint($_POST[ 'group_user' ]);

    if ($row_id <= 0) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Invalid item id', 'group-shop'));

    }

    if (empty($type)) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Undefined item type', 'group-shop'));

    }

    if ($id <= 0) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Invalid item', 'group-shop'));

    }

    if ($qty <= 0) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('At lest one quantity is required', 'group-shop'));

    }

    // instantiate cart object
    $cart = new Group_Shop_Cart();

    if ($type == 'p') {

        // update product
        if ($cart->update_product($row_id, $id, $qty, $group_user)) {

            // show success message once record updated
            wp_send_json_success(__('Item is updated', 'group-shop'));

        } else {

            // throw error if fails to update record
            wp_send_json_error(__('There is nothing to update', 'group-shop'));

        }

        // stop further execution once all process is done
        wp_die();

    } elseif ($type == 'pg') {

        // update product group

    } else {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Invalid item type', 'group-shop'));

    }


}
```

## HTML Markup

```
<table class="gs-orders-table">
    <caption class="cart-total">Order Total</caption>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="content-cart-title">Products</td>
        <td class="content-cart-price">5 042,00 kr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content-cart-title">Product Groups</td>
        <td class="content-cart-price">8 578,00 kr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content-cart-title cart-total">Total</td>
        <td class="content-cart-price cart-total">13 620,00 kr</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

FYI, I have a method in the class that returns various values for the cart. So if I can use this to update total in cart after ajax success.

## Cart Method Array

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [count] => 5
            [qty] => 15
            [total_raw] => 5042
            [total_formatted] => 5 042,00 kr
        )

    [product_groups] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
            [qty] => 6
            [total_raw] => 8578
            [total_formatted] => 8 578,00 kr
        )

    [cart] => Array
        (
            [count] => 8
            [qty] => 21
            [cart_total] => 13620
            [cart_total_formatted] => 13 620,00 kr
        )

)
```

Comment: Is it a WordPress bug? No.

Comment: Maybe I am not so clear with the question. I want to update the total after modifying the cart items qty.

Comment: WordPress does not have any cart. Ask to your plugin suppplier.

Comment: I have been using WordPress since long and pretty much aware that WordPress doesn't have a built-in cart. I just wonder if you ready my question correctly or understood correctly because on the very first line, the first sentence is describing that I am making a custom cart plugin. And even if it is for any third-party plugin who said I cannot ask the question here?

Comment: I was wrong, my apologies.

Comment: @MaxYudin That's okay :)